# jupyter "%matplotlib notebook" not showing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter

I want to create a notebook with interactive matplotlib plots. I can show static plots (`%matplotlib inline` works fine) but with `%matplotlib notebook` no figure shows up, not within the notebook nor as a pop-up window.

conda installed ipython 5.1.0,
jupyter 4.0.6
matplotlib 2.0 ('2.0.0b4+2344.g7b27a1b')

here is the notebook https://github.com/fedhere/notebookTests/blob/master/mplnotebook_test.ipynb

what am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: IPython 5.1.0, jupyter 4.2.1 and matplotlib 1.5.1 (python3) works fine for me.
Is python2 or python3?

Comment: neither sadly, but the parameters above are for python3

Comment: It works for me with jupyter 4.0.6 and matplotlib 1.5 on python 2.7. Mind that changing the backend from inline to notebook may not always work, so does this issue occur even with a newly started kernel? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342452/why-does-matplotlib-pyploy-imshow-change-it-axes).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with matplotlib 2 beta & rc versions. I thought I had tested it with matplotlib1.5 as well, but I had still loaded matplotlib2. I am reporting it [there](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7695).